# How do I customize the title of an example in a powershell function

Tags: powershell

Consider the following Powershell command:

```
Get-Help Get-Help -examples
```

When I execute it, the examples look something like this:

```
----- Example 1: Display basic information about a command -----

Get-Help Format-Table
Get-Help -Name Format-Table
Format-Table -?

These commands display basic information about the `Format-Table` cmdlet.

`Get-Help <name>` is the simplest and default syntax of `Get-Help` cmdlet. You can omit the parameter name ( Name ).

`<command-name> -?` works only for commands.
```

When I tag a Powershell method with .EXAMPLE, like so:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Does stuff

.DESCRIPTION
Details about doing stuff

.PARAMETER Foo
Foos things

.EXAMPLE
Invoke-FooBar -Foo bar, baz
Foos the bar and baz
#>
```

It gives me an example like so:

```
-------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

PS C:\>Invoke-FooBar -Foo bar, baz

Foos the bar and baz
```

My question is, how do I change the title so that it describes what I'm demonstrating?

Comment: You don't, the example names are automatically generated by the comment-based help subsystem

Answer (score 3):

You can't - the examples extracted from comment-based help is converted to XML by an internal [`HelpCommentsParser`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/f4a50eda0d162ecb3217066f4b5dd2d5498dd7ef/src/System.Management.Automation/help/HelpCommentsParser.cs#L354), which constructs the title string for each example with this statement:

```
string titleStr = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "\t\t\t\t-------------------------- {0} {1} --------------------------",
    HelpDisplayStrings.ExampleUpperCase, count++);
```

The [relevant resource file](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/8aec1585195e6d4871538aaa2ad2b112cf5fbfee/src/System.Management.Automation/resources/HelpDisplayStrings.resx#L157) contains the word `EXAMPLE` for the `HelpDisplayStrings.ExampleUpper` value, which is why it always shows up as `EXAMPLE 1`, `EXAMPLE 2` etc.

---

<sup>*code linked above is from PowerShell Core 6, but the comment-based help facility hasn't seen any major change since version 3.0*</sup>

Comment: How does Microsoft get the output to be `Example 1: Display help about the help system` from `Get-Help Get-Help -Examples`? Are they not using the `.EXAMPLE` tag?

Comment: @lit my answer deals with _script functions and comment-based help_ - the `Get-Help` command is binary and forwards to an XML-based help file (See output from `Get-Command Get-Help |fl`)